# public inline fun String.toFloat(): Float defined in kotlin.text

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code in my **DestinationCreateActivity.kt** that create new data, how do i convert the text to float?

**DestinationCreateActivity.kt**

```
newDestination.amount = amount.text.toFloat()
```

[image]

this is my activity_destiny_create.xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Amount"
        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"/>
```

my model

```
@Field("amount") amount: Float,
```

this is the error

[image]

Comment: whats the issue here

Comment: @ShaluTD toFloat doesnt work or something in my code missing or gone wrong

Comment: check the image sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `amount.text` is not `String` but its `CharSequence`. So, you should convert it to `String` and then convert to `Float`:

```
amount.text.toString().toFloat()
```